# SVG Custom Cursor

Tags: svg, cursor

I'm trying to use **SVG custom cursor** but having a trouble to make it work. I thing the code is wrong but I can´t find the solution. Any idea?

**Here is the code I'm using:**

```
.tontcho-home-cursor:hover {
  cursor: url('<svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 427.39 266.72"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>TW_Custom-Cursor1</title><path class="cls-1" d="M207.45,150a49.57,49.57,0,1,1-14.52-35A49.19,49.19,0,0,1,207.45,150Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><path d="M203.54,150a45.75,45.75,0,1,0-13.4,32.24A45.35,45.35,0,0,0,203.54,150Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M183.16,156.27l3.63,1.26-.55,1.81a30.12,30.12,0,0,1-10.75,14.8,29.46,29.46,0,0,1-17.59,5.72,29.87,29.87,0,0,1-17.73-5.72,29,29,0,0,1-10.6-14.8l-.7-1.81,3.77-1.26.56,2a25.69,25.69,0,0,0,24.7,17.86,26.21,26.21,0,0,0,15.35-5,26.56,26.56,0,0,0,9.22-12.84Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="140.6 132.13 136.41 132.13 136.41 128.36 148.55 128.36 148.55 132.13 144.37 132.13 144.37 145.38 140.6 145.38 140.6 132.13"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="171.58 132.13 167.4 132.13 167.4 128.36 179.54 128.36 179.54 132.13 175.49 132.13 175.49 145.38 171.58 145.38 171.58 132.13"/><path class="cls-1" d="M427.25,202.72a64,64,0,1,1-18.75-45.25A63.55,63.55,0,0,1,427.25,202.72Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><path d="M422.2,202.72a59.1,59.1,0,1,0-17.31,41.64A58.62,58.62,0,0,0,422.2,202.72Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M395.88,210.83l4.69,1.62-.72,2.35A38.91,38.91,0,0,1,386,233.91a38.07,38.07,0,0,1-22.71,7.39,38.62,38.62,0,0,1-22.9-7.39,37.43,37.43,0,0,1-13.7-19.11l-.9-2.35,4.87-1.62.72,2.52a33.2,33.2,0,0,0,31.91,23.08,33.86,33.86,0,0,0,19.83-6.49A34.31,34.31,0,0,0,395,213.35Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="340.86 179.64 335.45 179.64 335.45 174.77 351.13 174.77 351.13 179.64 345.73 179.64 345.73 196.77 340.86 196.77 340.86 179.64"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="380.88 179.64 375.47 179.64 375.47 174.77 391.15 174.77 391.15 179.64 385.93 179.64 385.93 196.77 380.88 196.77 380.88 179.64"/><path class="cls-1" d="M413.27,45a45,45,0,1,1-13.19-31.82A44.68,44.68,0,0,1,413.27,45Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><path d="M409.72,45a41.5,41.5,0,1,0-41.45,41.45A41.55,41.55,0,0,0,409.72,45Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M391.21,50.7l3.3,1.15L394,53.49a27.36,27.36,0,0,1-9.76,13.44,26.76,26.76,0,0,1-16,5.2,27.14,27.14,0,0,1-16.1-5.2,26.31,26.31,0,0,1-9.64-13.44l-.63-1.64,3.42-1.15.51,1.78a23.37,23.37,0,0,0,22.44,16.23,23.8,23.8,0,0,0,13.94-4.57,24.06,24.06,0,0,0,8.37-11.66Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="352.57 28.77 348.76 28.77 348.76 25.35 359.79 25.35 359.79 28.77 355.99 28.77 355.99 40.82 352.57 40.82 352.57 28.77"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="380.71 28.77 376.9 28.77 376.9 25.35 387.93 25.35 387.93 28.77 384.26 28.77 384.26 40.82 380.71 40.82 380.71 28.77"/><path d="M49.65,199.26a49.27,49.27,0,1,1,34.84-14.43A48.94,48.94,0,0,1,49.65,199.26Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><path d="M49.65,101.24a48.75,48.75,0,1,1-34.47,14.28,48.64,48.64,0,0,1,34.47-14.28m0-1a49.8,49.8,0,1,0,35.21,14.58A49.49,49.49,0,0,0,49.65,100.2Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M94.56,150a45,45,0,0,0-76.77-31.86,45,45,0,1,0,63.58,63.58A44.54,44.54,0,0,0,94.56,150Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><path d="M49.65,179.9a29.9,29.9,0,0,1-17.75-5.73,29.16,29.16,0,0,1-10.63-14.83l-.87-2.25,4.75-1.59.7,2.45a25.39,25.39,0,0,0,8.88,12.37,25.8,25.8,0,0,0,14.92,4.83,24.77,24.77,0,0,0,23.67-17.22l.87-2.42,4.53,1.57L78,159.35a30.37,30.37,0,0,1-10.76,14.82A29.74,29.74,0,0,1,49.65,179.9Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><path d="M74.51,156.17l3.57,1.24-.55,1.78A29.6,29.6,0,0,1,67,173.75a28.94,28.94,0,0,1-17.3,5.63,29.35,29.35,0,0,1-17.44-5.63,28.57,28.57,0,0,1-10.44-14.56l-.68-1.78,3.71-1.24.54,1.92a25.29,25.29,0,0,0,24.31,17.58,25.83,25.83,0,0,0,15.11-4.94,26.14,26.14,0,0,0,9.06-12.64l.69-1.92m-49-1.33-1,.34-3.71,1.24-1,.34.39,1,.67,1.75a29.63,29.63,0,0,0,10.8,15.05,30.67,30.67,0,0,0,36,0,30.71,30.71,0,0,0,11-15.07l.56-1.81.29-1-1-.33-3.57-1.24-1-.33-.35,1-.68,1.92a24.26,24.26,0,0,1-23.19,16.89A25.29,25.29,0,0,1,35,169.88a24.91,24.91,0,0,1-8.68-12.11l-.54-1.89-.3-1Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><polygon points="32.11 145.98 32.11 132.94 27.99 132.94 27.99 128.18 40.98 128.18 40.98 132.94 36.86 132.94 36.86 145.98 32.11 145.98"/><path d="M40.31,128.71v3.7H36.19v13.05h-3.7V132.41H28.37v-3.7H40.31m1-1.05h-14v5.8h4.12v13h5.8v-13h4.12v-5.8Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/><polygon points="62.59 145.98 62.59 132.94 58.47 132.94 58.47 128.18 71.47 128.18 71.47 132.94 67.48 132.94 67.48 145.98 62.59 145.98"/><path d="M70.8,128.71v3.7h-4v13.05H63V132.41H58.85v-3.7H70.8m1-1.05h-14v5.8h4.12v13h5.93v-13h4v-5.8Z" transform="translate(0.14 0)"/></svg>'), pointer !important;
}
```

Comment: Well I have checked the other answer and I still not see a solution...

Comment: Why not? Your URL is currently invalid as it contains # characters, they need to be replaced by %23. The answer to the other question contains a working cursor.